# Sun Java not loading UnixPrincipal (Ubuntu 12)

Tags: java, classloader

Im getting this very odd error with sun java and ubuntu.

> "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.sun.security.auth.UnixPrincipal"

This class appears to be a sun specific class, and i have a fresh, working version of sun java 1.6 on ubuntu 12.04.  I have confirmed that my version of java is the correct one which is being used to run by class, and in fact, that the other versions (like openjdk) are not interfering.

Here are my specs :

> $ java -version java version "1.6.0_33" Java(TM) SE Runtime
>   Environment (build 1.6.0_33-b03) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
>   (build 20.8-b03, mixed mode)
>
> $ lsb_release -a No LSB modules are available. Distributor ID:
>   Ubuntu Description:    Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Release:    12.04 Codename:
>   precise

The error :

> home/vagrant/Development/workspace/xxxxx/build.xml:222:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/security/auth/UnixPrincipal
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.(UserGroupInformation.java:246)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.(FileSystem.java:1436)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1337)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:244)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:122) ... Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.sun.security.auth.UnixPrincipal
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1361)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1311)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1070)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
>       ... 38 more

'First, I thought this just meant that the class wasnt in my sun installation'

But the following :

> unzip -l /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/lib/rt.jar | grep UnixPrincipal

revealed :

> 1272  2012-05-09 10:19  com/sun/security/auth/UnixPrincipal.class

And, by checking System.getProperties(), I found :

> java.ext.dirs=....usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.33/jre/lib/rt.jar.....

Thus indicating that this class is in a jar which is certainly in the Runtime version of my java !

Thus, somehow, the java runtime is not able to load this class.  I wonder why ?

One minor note : Im running it via ant 1.8.  However, I dont think this should effect anything, since the Ant classloader is, I believe, relatively stable.

Comment: Do you have another JVM installed?

Comment: i believe that gcj might be on the machine, but clearly, the runtime in question is using the sun JVM (as indicated by System.getProperties).

Answer (score 1):

You've probably solved this by now, but here's my recent tangle with the same problem:

Both Sun java and gcj installed.  Running interactively gave me the Sun java and the `UnixPrincipal` class loads correctly.  Running non-interactively (`service myservice start`) would not properly set `JAVA_HOME` and the system would use gcj instead and `UnixPrincipal` fails to load.  Explicitly setting `JAVA_HOME` in my service script resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem trying to use [ant](https://ant.apache.org) to run Solr.  While I had `JAVA_HOME` set up for Oracle JDK8, I believe that `ant` may have been finding the openjdk install on my Ubuntu 15.10 computer.

The solution to the problem was to include the `fork="true"` option in the `<java>` task:

```xml
<java fork="true" classname="com.mycompany.MyMainClassName">
```

By including the `fork="true"` option, it created a 2nd JVM using the `java` command which correctly found my Oracle JDK.  If you do not include the `fork="true"`  option, the user program is run inside the same JVM that `ant` is using (which may not be the JDK you intend).

For reference, the full error stacktrace was:

```
 [java] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/security/auth/UnixPrincipal
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute(ExecuteJava.java:195)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.run(Java.java:772)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:222)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:136)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute(Java.java:109)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:853)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:285)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:112)
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/security/auth/UnixPrincipal
     [java]     at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.<clinit>(UserGroupInformation.java:336)
     [java]     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:1765)
     [java]     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:1758)
     [java]     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1626)
     [java]     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:254)
     [java]     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:123)
     [java]     at com.touchcommerce.engagementloader.EngagementLoader.getFileSystem(EngagementLoader.java:342)
     [java]     at com.touchcommerce.engagementloader.EngagementLoader.load(EngagementLoader.java:364)
     [java]     at com.touchcommerce.engagementloader.EngagementLoader.main(EngagementLoader.java:454)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.run(ExecuteJava.java:218)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute(ExecuteJava.java:153)
     [java]     ... 21 more
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.security.auth.UnixPrincipal
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1388)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1337)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1095)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
     [java]     ... 36 more
     [java] Java Result: -1
```